# Navigating back in elections doesn't work

Tags: bug, election, election-page

On the elections site, navigation using the browser buttons are broken.

Steps to reproduce:

- Go here: http://elections.stackexchange.com/;
- Click on your favorite site;
- Click your browsers *Back* button.

In my browser (Chrome latest), it still shows the site I selected, and it doesn't return to the main page. It does change the URL, the content isn't changed.

If you hit refresh, the main page shows, but clicking *Forward* doesn't work either.

Comment: Repro'ed . . . On Chrome latest. :P

Comment: Yep, repro on Safari latest. I think most browsers have an API for overriding the back button, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes. I guess the history API is being used but the state isn't restored correctly.